# Looping condition n times with reference to n no. of rows from another table in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a reference time table `TimeTable` and another data table `Datatable` as in image.
[image]

I am trying to get `Ref_Time` as custom column in `DataTable` with below code. As a workaround I hardcoded the time here. How I can eliminate this. Considering the no.of rows may vary in `TimeTable`.

```
Ref_Time = IF(
            TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:35:00 AM") , "6:00:00 AM",
            IF(
                TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:30:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:35:00 AM"), "5:30:00 AM",
                IF(
                    TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:25:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:30:00 AM"), "5:25:00 AM",
                    IF(
                        TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:20:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:25:00 AM"), "5:20:00 AM",
                        IF(
                            TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:15:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:20:00 AM"), "5:15:00 AM",
                            IF(
                                TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:10:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:15:00 AM"), "5:10:00 AM",
                                IF(
                                    TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:05:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:10:00 AM"), "5:05:00 AM",
                                    IF(
                                        TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("5:00:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:05:00 AM"), "5:00:00 AM",
                                        IF(
                                            TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("4:55:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("5:00:00 AM"), "4:55:00 AM",
                                            IF(
                                                TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) >= TIMEVALUE("2:00:00 AM") && TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("4:55:00 AM"), "2:00:00 AM",
                                                IF(
                                                    TIMEVALUE(DataTable[endTime]) < TIMEVALUE("2:00:00 AM") , "1:00:00 AM"
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: So... your DAX doesn't work?

Comment: Its working.. but I want to eliminate hardcoded values

Answer (score 0):

This should be a little easier to read, and should do what you need:

```
Ref_Time =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:35:00 AM" ), "6:00:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:30:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:35:00 AM" )
    ), "5:30:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:25:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:30:00 AM" )
    ), "5:25:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:20:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:25:00 AM" )
    ), "5:20:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:15:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:20:00 AM" )
    ), "5:15:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:10:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:15:00 AM" )
    ), "5:10:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:05:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:10:00 AM" )
    ), "5:05:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "5:00:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:05:00 AM" )
    ), "5:00:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "4:55:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "5:00:00 AM" )
    ), "4:55:00 AM",
    AND (
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) >= TIMEVALUE ( "2:00:00 AM" ),
        TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "4:55:00 AM" )
    ), "2:00:00 AM",
    TIMEVALUE ( DataTable[endTime] ) < TIMEVALUE ( "2:00:00 AM" ), "1:00:00 AM"
)
```

Comment: Yeah, this should work.. it should take less time to read as well. Is it possible to remove hardcoded times and pick it from the table itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You want to be able to dynamically select a date from the table and display this value where?

Comment: yes Steliok, considering the no. of rows may vary in `TimeTable`